# Jquery - select2 en elemento td de tabla

Tags: jquery, html, select2

Hola tengo una tabla en donde los elementos td pueden ser editados en linea (doble click y un elemento input se agrega para que la celda pueda ser editada). Tengo algunas columnas donde es necesario tener una lista de valores predefinidos y en donde quiero utilizar la libreria "select2". Esta es la parte del código donde agrego los elementos input o select de acuerdo a la columna donde el usuario ha hecho doble click:

```
if(tipo !== "checkbox" && !$(this).find("input, select").hasClass('editbox')) {
if(columna === 'distrito_contacto') {
    $(this).html('<select class="editbox"></select>');
    $('.editbox').select2({
        placeholder: "Distrito...",
        allowClear: true,
        width: '100%',
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        ajax: {
            url: "php/listaOpciones.php?tabla=distrito&columna=distrito",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            language: 'select2-es',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    valor: params.term,
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                return markup;
            },
            cache: true
        },
        minimumInputLength: 0
    });
}                               
else $(this).html('<input type="' + tipo + '" class="editbox" value="' + origContent +'" />');
```

Esta es una imagen del resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema ocurre cuando el elemento select2 es añadido, el contenedor del mismo "salta" de la posición donde debería estar y adicionalmente no funciona correctamente. Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: Creería que no funciona bien al no estar el elemento .editbox en el DOM inicial, has probado con la opción `dropdownParent: #idTdContenedor` ? o agregar un handler de eventos como `click()`  o `on()` ?

Comment: hola Shaz gracias por las recomendaciones, voy a probar agregando la opción dropdownParent.. la segunda recomendación no la entiendo bien, podrías detallarla tal vez con un ejemplo?

Comment: Algo así: http://jsfiddle.net/ej3jfaqf/ , o puedes buscar en la documentación de jQuery ambos métodos.

Comment: No conozco select2, pero parece que agrega los nuevos elementos a un `<select>` con la clase `.editbox`. ¿Podría ser que existe otro elemento `.editbox` antes en el DOM al que los está agregando? (Tal vez uno de los creados anteriormente como `<input>` que no fue eliminado del DOM.)

Comment: la recomendacion de Shaz solucionó el problema. Faltaba indicarle al elemento el contenedor padre para que se ajustara en la posición correcta. Gracias!